# Quel est le sens de l'expression « faut le faire » dans ce contexte?

Tags: sens, expressions, vocabulaire

Dans un livre du méthode Assimil pour apprendre le français, j'ai trouvé ce texte avec l'expression « faut le faire » ( j'y ai ajouté les caractères en gras):

> Il a gagné au Loto mais il a perdu son ticket. **Faut le faire** !

Je ne comprends pas la signification de cette expression en ce contexte. Je l'ai cherchée dans l'entrée "faire" du *Trésor  la langue française*, mais je ne l'ai pas trouvée. Quelqu'un pourrait-il m'expliquer le sens?

Comment: My guess is an implied "en prendre soin" or something.

Answer (score 2):

L'expression est ironique.

Normalement, ***il faut le faire !*** signifie que faire quelque chose est difficile, demande beaucoup d'efforts, de travail mais ici, elle signifie au contraire que ce qui a été fait est une grosse bêtise, une bourde, une maladresse.

TLFi **[II. - A.- 1.](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/faire)**

> − Familier *(Il) faut le faire!* [Pour marquer l'admiration ou, par ironie, le dénigrement]

Larousse [**Faire**](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/faire/32701)

> Familier. *(Il) faut le faire*, cela ne paraît pas difficile, mais en réalité il s'agit d'un exploit.

le Robert, [**Faire**](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/faire)

> familier *(il) faut le faire* : il faut en être capable, c'est difficile.

En espagnol, ce serait peut-être *¡Qué hazaña!*, *¡Qué proeza!*, *¡Bien hecho!* et peut-être en catalan *Ben fet!*

En anglais *Good job!* ou mieux : *Brilliant!* souvent ironique.

Comment: En catalan je ne dirais jamais "Quina gesta!". Les suggestions en espagnol sont mieux comprises, mais je ne pense pas qu'il s'agisse d'expressions idiomatiques.

Comment: [**Familier. (Il) faut le faire**, cela ne paraît pas difficile, mais en réalité il s'agit d'un exploit.](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/faire/32701): ça serait un autre exemple d'utilisation de cette expression, n'est-ce pas?

Comment: @Charo 1. Ok, le catalan n'est pas bon. C'était des tentatives et j'ai mis "peut-être" pour ça. Est-ce que *¡bien hecho!* (Ben fet!) ? iraient mieux? 2. Oui, la page du Larousse correspond exactement à cette expression. Elle n'est pas utilisée ironiquement dans l'explication associée.